# External Identity User and Experience Cloud

Tags: community, licenses, experience-cloud, identity

Do i Need to buy the External Identity Licenses to make possible use Salesforce Experience Cloud as IDP? Or can i use the Community Licenses?

Comment: Community (Exp Cloud) includes Identity. https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.exp_cloud_plan_licenses.htm&type=5